# How can I find the mode of a number in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, mode

I am sorry if this question is repetitive, but I am trying to find the mode of an array. This method takes in an integer array as an input and returns the integer that is the mode of the array. Here is my code below:

```
public static int mode(int[] abc) {
        int count = 1;
        int number = 0;
        int finalCount = 0;
        int finalNum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
            int j = 0;
            for(int k = i + j; k < abc.length; j++) {
                int x = abc[i];
                if(x == abc[k]) {
                    number = x;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count > finalCount) {
                finalCount = count;
                finalNum = number;
            }else if(count == finalCount && count > 0 && i != abc.length - 1) {
                if(finalNum > number) {
                    finalNum = number;
                }
            }else if(count == finalCount && count == 0 && i == abc.length - 1) {
                for(int l = 0; l < abc.length - 1; l++) {
                    int m = abc[0];
                    if(m > abc[l + 1]) {
                        finalNum = abc[l + 1];
                    }else {
                        finalNum = m;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return finalNum;
    }
```

Apparently, this method says it needs to return a result of type int. But if I already have finalNum, which is supposed to be the mode, to be returned, then why is it giving me this error?

Comment: `for(int k = i + j; k < abc.length; j++) {` do you mean to increment `j`, or should it be `k`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I meant to do j, but incrementing k would essentially do the same thing, no?

Comment: You don't read `j` in the loop, so incrementing `j` has no effect.

Comment: I suspect that the specific problem you're having here is that you've written `return finalNum;` inside the outermost loop.

Comment: @AndyTurner So how would I go about trying to fix that?

Comment: Actually, no, I'm wrong, the braces are in the correct place. But it also compiles without an error. So... not sure how you're getting that problem.